# Физика персонажа

Tags: c#, разработка-игр, unity3d

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class MovePlayer : MonoBehaviour {
    public Vector3 speed;
    private Rigidbody rb;
    private float moveH;
    private bool jump;
    private Vector3 velocityChange;
    private float rGround = 1.0f;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody> ();
        speed = new Vector3(10.0f,0.0f, 0.0f);
    }

    void Update(){
        moveH = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        jump = Input.GetButtonDown ("Jump");
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate () {
        velocityChange = moveH * speed - rb.velocity;
        rb.AddForce (velocityChange, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
        if (Physics.Raycast (transform.position, -Vector3.up, rGround) && jump) {
            rb.AddForce (new Vector3(0.0f, 90.0f, 0.0f), ForceMode.Impulse);
        }
     }
}
```

После прыжка, персонаж опускается еле еле. Масса 1. Гравитация -9. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: я конечно не специалист в **unity**, но хотелось бы узнать, а вы уверены, что гравитация может быть отрицательной?

Comment: Да. Это постоянное воздействие по оси Y. Поэтому вектор направлен вниз.

Comment: Спасибо, буду знать

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это должно исправить проблему.

```
void FixedUpdate()
{
    velocityChange = moveH * speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime;
    rb.AddForce(velocityChange, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
    if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, -Vector3.up, rGround) && jump)
    {
        rb.AddForce(new Vector3(0.0f, 5.0f, 0.0f), ForceMode.Impulse);
        jump = !jump;
    }
}
```

С большой вероятностью, ошибка в строке

> velocityChange = moveH * speed - rb.velocity;

Силу, которую необходимо добавить, не нужно вычислять путем вычисления из силы добавления текущей скорости объекта. Достаточно лишь вычислить какую силу, которую стоит добавить к объекту и использовать `AddForce`.

При падении, скорость падения не может увеличиваться и всегда составляет `moveH * speed`, т. к. скорость, полученная при разгоне объекта во время падения сводилась к нулю на каждом апдейте.

Comment: Спасибо, всё верно. Работает. Но я столкнулся со следующей проблемой. Создал физ. материал. где динамик и статик трение ноль, режим мультиплай. Чтобы когда жмешь вперед, объект сползал со стены, а не висел к ней как прилипший пока жмешь вперед. Но теперь когда двигаешь объект, он как на катке. Долго скользит перед затуханием, но к стенам зато не прилипает. Как сделать, чтобы объект после прекращения нажатия клавиши перестал двигаться?

Comment: Решение нашел. Просто этот материал нужно не на персонажа, а на стены применить. Но все же момент, перед полной остановкой есть. В результат страдает отклик. Можно как нибудь останавливать его по быстрей?